# How do I prevent Schema fields from being inserted into subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a dating app in node js and vue, and everything works however I wish to exclude password from being inserted into subdocument upon creation of a conversation. Right now I know that i can say `.select('-password')` when using `User.findOne()` but it doesn't work, when adding the user schema as a subdoc to my Conversations schema, which has user_one and user_two, each referring to a User schema. I need the password field, so I can't ommit it when creating a schema. Right Now my code looks like this:

```
User.findOne({ _id: fromUserId }, (errUserOne, userOne) => {
        User.findOne({ _id: toUserId }, (errUserTwo, userTwo) => {
          conversation = new Conversation({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            user_one: userOne,
            user_two: userTwo
          });

          conversation.save();

          const message = new Message({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            conversation_id: conversation._id,
            message: req.body.message,
            user_id: fromUserId
          });

          message.save();

          res.sendStatus(201);
        });
      });
```

However this code saves the password to the Conversation collection, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.find({ _id: :{ $in : [fromUserId,toUserId] }, { password:0 } , (err, userArray) => {
  //your code goes here
});
```

Two things, You are querying two time for getting users. You can merge it into single query and for excluding the password field you can pass `{password:0}`. Which will exclude it in the documents.

also while you define `Conversation` schema don't make `user_one` and `user_two` type of user. Instead define only whatever properties of user you want to save like:

```
var Conversation = new Schema({
   _id   : ObjectId, 
  user_one : {
   _id: ObjectId,
   //all other fields
  },
  user_two : {
   _id: ObjectId,
   //all other fields
  },
});
```